# Working MvvM and Concurrency

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, concurrency

I am developing an application using WPF and MvvM, written in C#. I am still a beginner with the some of the concepts of MvvM and the entity framework. I have what seems like everything working except the concurrency issue. I worked through this [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171936.aspx), and it didn't work for me. So, like the MvvM structure, I have a model and entities file called *BackflowManagementEntities*. I then have a repository which handles the update for a tester. I inserted try and catch here for testing and no luck.

```
private BackflowManagementEntities dbContext;
internal void SaveChanges()
{
      try
      {
           dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
      }
      catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
      {
           Console.WriteLine("Concurrency Exception : " + ex.Message);
      }
}
```

So I have a three part question :

1. This is the only place I can think of that I should be implementing the concurrency check. Please let me know if I am wrong.
2. Is this the correct exception/way to check for the concurrency error? I understand how to deal with the concurrency error, I just don't know how to catch it.
3. Is there any source you would recommend me reading on dealing with and catching concurrency exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Saving Changes and Managing Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx) MSDN article...

> By default, the Entity Framework
>   implements an optimistic concurrency
>   model. This means that locks are not
>   held on data in the data source
>   between when the data is queried and
>   the data is updated. The Entity
>   Framework saves object changes to the
>   database without checking for
>   concurrency. For entities that might
>   experience a high degree of
>   concurrency, we recommend that the
>   entity define a property in the
>   conceptual layer with an attribute of
>   ConcurrencyMode="fixed", as shown in
>   the following example:
>
> Any conflicting changes will cause an
>   [OptimisticConcurrencyException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.optimisticconcurrencyexception.aspx).

For more information, see [How to: Manage Data Concurrency in the Object Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399228.aspx).

In short, change the `ConcurrencyMode` to Fixed and catch the `OptimisticConcurrencyException` exception...

Answer (score 1):

I know i am very late to this but this is something a lot of developers face whiles developing multi-threaded application using entity framework and wpf.
Now here is a couple of things you have to take note of

1. ) you cannot access the ui thread from background thread.
2. ) Dbcontext is not thread safe so using it in a multi-threaded
   enverioment might cause problems if care is not taken

So here is the way i have solve this problem.My solution follows the abstract repository pattern.
The participation classes and interfaces are:

1. DataRepository and IDataRepository
2. Student and IStudent
3. StudentViewModel
4. EntityBase

This is IDataRepository

```
 public interface IDataRepository 
        {
            void AddAsync<T>(T entity, Action<T>callBack,Action<Exception>exceptionCallback=null) where T : EntityBase;
            void DeleteAsync<T>(int[] ids, Action callBack, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null) where T : EntityBase;
            void UpdateAsync<T>(T entity, Action<T> callBack, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null) where T : EntityBase;
            void FindAsync<T>(int id, Action<T> callBack, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null) where T : EntityBase;
           void FindAsync<T>(Action<List<T>> callBack,Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate=null, int? pageIndex=0, int? pageSize=20, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : EntityBase;
        }
```

### This is DataRepository

```
 public class Repository<TContext>: IDataRepository
       
       where TContext:DbContext,new ()
   {
     
        protected static void ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<List<T>> task, Action<List<T>> callback, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null) where T : EntityBase
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Result = task();
            };
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error == null && callback != null)
                    callback((List<T>)e.Result);
                else if (e.Error != null && exceptionCallback != null)
                    exceptionCallback(e.Error);
            };
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        protected static void ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<T> task, Action<T> callback, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null) where T : EntityBase
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Result = task();
            };
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error == null && callback != null)
                    callback((T)e.Result);
                else if (e.Error != null && exceptionCallback != null)
                    exceptionCallback(e.Error);
            };
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        protected static void ExecuteAsync(Action task, Action callback, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null)
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
            {
               task();
            };
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error == null && callback != null)
                    callback();
                else if (e.Error != null && exceptionCallback != null)
                    exceptionCallback(e.Error);
            };
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


        public void AddAsync<T>(T entity, Action<T> callBack, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null) where T : EntityBase
        {
            ExecuteAsync(() =>
            {
                using (var context = new TContext())
                {
                   var addedEntity = context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return addedEntity;
                }
            },callBack,exceptionCallback);
            
       }

       public void DeleteAsync<T>(int[] ids, Action callBack, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null) where T : EntityBase
        {
            ExecuteAsync(() =>
            {
                using (var context = new TContext())
                {
                   var entitiesToRemove = context.Set<T>().Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
                    foreach (var entity in entitiesToRemove)
                    {
                        context.Entry(entity).State=EntityState.Deleted;
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();                    
                }
            },callBack, exceptionCallback);
        }

       public void UpdateAsync<T>(T entity, Action<T> callBack, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null) where T : EntityBase
        {
           ExecuteAsync(() =>
           {
               using (var context=new TContext())
               {
                 context.Entry(entity).State=EntityState.Modified;
                   context.SaveChanges();
                   var updatedEntity = context.Set<T>().Find(entity.Id);
                   return updatedEntity;
               }
           },callBack,exceptionCallback);
       }

       public void FindAsync<T>(int id, Action<T> callBack, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback = null) where T : EntityBase
        {
           ExecuteAsync(() =>
           {
               using (var context=new TContext())
               {
                   var entity = context.Set<T>().Find(id);
                   return entity;
               }
           },callBack,exceptionCallback);
       }

       public void FindAsync<T>(Action<List<T>> callBack, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate=null, int? pageIndex = 0, int? pageSize = 20, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : EntityBase
        {
           ExecuteAsync(() =>
           {
               using (var context=new TContext())
               {
                   var query = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

                   if (includes != null)
                   {
                       query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
                   }
                   if (predicate != null)
                       query = query.Where(predicate);

                   var offset = (pageIndex ?? 0) * (pageSize ?? 15);
                   query = query.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).Skip(offset).Take(pageSize ?? 15);

                   return query.ToList();
               } 
           },callBack);
       }
   }
```

### this is Student Repository and IStudentRepository

```
  public interface IStudentRepository:IDataRepository
    {
         void AddGuardian(Gurdian gurdian, int studentId,Action<Student> callBack);
         void SaveStudent(Student student, Gurdian gurdian,Action<Student>callBack);         
         void GetPrimaryGurdian(int studentId,Action<Gurdian> callBack );
        
    }




[Export(typeof(IStudentRepository))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class StudentRepository : Repository<StudentContext>, IStudentRepository
    {
        public void AddGuardian(Gurdian gurdian, int studentId, Action<Student> callBack)
        {
           FindAsync<Student>(studentId, (student) =>
           {
               student.Gurdians.Add(gurdian);
               UpdateAsync(student, callBack);
           });
        }

        public void SaveStudent(Student student, Gurdian gurdian, Action<Student> callBack)
        {
          student.Gurdians.Add(gurdian);
            AddAsync(student, callBack);
        }

        public void GetPrimaryGurdian(int studentId, Action<Gurdian> callBack)
        {
           FindAsync<Student>(studentId,(student)=> { callBack(student.PrimaryGurdian); });
        }
    }
```

### Then finally Your viewModel

```
[Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public class StudentViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {        
       
        private readonly IStudentRepository _repository;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public StudentViewModel()
        {
                      
            _repository =new StudentRepository();

            Student = new Student();         
            SaveStudentCommand = new RelayCommand(OnStudentSaveExcute, CanSaveStudent);
           
        }

       

        #region Properties
        private Student _student;

        public Student Student
        {
            get { return _student; }
            set { _student = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => Student); }
        }

      
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

        public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
        {
            get { return _students; }
            set { _students = value; }
        }

       

        #endregion

        #region Commands
        public ICommand SaveStudentCommand { get; set; }


        private void OnStudentSaveExcute()
        {
          
            
            _repository.SaveStudent(Student,Gurdian, (student) =>
            {
                _students.Add(student);
            });

        }
       
        #endregion
       

        private  void LoadStudents()
        {
            
            _repository.FindAsync<Student>((students) =>
            {
                foreach(var student in students)
                _students.Add(student);
            });
        }
     
    }
```

---

```
public class EntityBase{
public int get{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Note in production,I use mef as DI to injuct the repositories.Infact i used a little nice pattern know as RepositoryFactory patern to facilitate this.you can contact me for the full source code at suulisindiyaka@stoicteam.com